# Rails PG::SyntaxError: ERROR Clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a strange error. I have **Customers** and **Messages....**
Customers has_many Messages.. and message belongs_to customer
The customer has a **phone** column and a message has a **to** column.
The code below is suppose to take the current customer id and grab the *phone* column then find all **messages** that match the *phone* based on the *to* column. Then update all the messages with the customer id.

I'm getting this error that I don't see the problem. **Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?** The error is triggered on the each loop. I tried to inspect @foundmessage_all but that doesn't work.

```
 PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "to" LINE 1: SELECT
 "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE (to = '2081234567'... ^ : SELECT
 "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE (to = '2081234567' )
```

*customer/show.rb*

```
 @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
 tempphone = @customer.phone
 @foundmessage_all = Message.where('to = ? ', tempphone)
       if @foundmessage_all != nil
          @foundmessage_all.each do |t|
          t.update_attribute(:customer_id, @customer.id)
          end
       else
          #other stuff
       end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to below statement:

```
@foundmessage_all = Message.where(to: tempphone)
```

If this doesn't solve the issue, post the full stack trace.

Also you should be checking `present?` on `@foundmessage_all` instead of `!= nil`

```
if @foundmessage_all.present?
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I'm a little new to rails. How can I get the full stack trace?

Comment: Ok I changed the 3rd line to 
@foundmessage_all = Message.where(:to => tempphone)
This version works.

Comment: Oh, that might be because of ruby version being older than 1.9, pl mark it as answer